# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: ethers.js, react

Here is code :

```js
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
    import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
    import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
    import { Contract, providers } from 'ethers';
    import {abi, WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS } from '../constants/index'
    
    export default function Home() {
      
      // walletConnected keep track of whether the user's wallet is connected or not
      const [walletConnected, setWalletConnected] = useState(false);
      // numberOfWhitelisted tracks the number of addresses's whitelisted
      const [numberOfWhitelisted, setNumberOfWhitelisted] = useState(0);
      // loading is set to true when we are waiting for a transaction to get mined
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      // joinedWhitelist keeps track of whether the current metamask address has joined the Whitelist or not
       const [joinedWhitelist, setJoinedWhitelist] = useState(false);
      // Create a reference to the Web3 Modal (used for connecting to Metamask) which persists as long as the page is open
      const web3Modalref = useRef()
    
    
      const getProviderOrSigner = async (needSigner = false)=>{
       try{
           // Connect to Metamask
           // Since we store `web3Modal` as a reference, we need to access the `current` value to get access to the underlying object
           const provider = await web3Modalref.current.connect() //this line returns provider and we're storing it in provider variable
           // variable provider is just an object, we can't do anything by it
           //by wrapping around it by Web3Provider object we can perform many operation like getting chain ID etc
           const web3Provider = new providers.Web3Provider(provider) 
     
           const {chainId} = await web3Provider.getNetwork()
           if(chainId !== 5){
              window.alert("Change the network to Goerli")
              throw new Error("Change network to Goerli")
           }
    
           //Get signer also if needSigner is true
           if(needSigner){
            const signer =  web3Provider.getSigner()
            return signer
           }
           return web3Provider
       }catch(err){
        console.error(err)
       }
      }
    
      const addAddressToWhitelist = async()=>{
          try{
               const signer = await  getProviderOrSigner(true)
               const whitelistContract = new Contract(
                WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS ,
                abi,
                signer
               )
               const tx = await whitelistContract.addAddressToWhitelist()
               setLoading(true)
               await tx.wait()
               setLoading(false)
               await getNumberofWhitelisted()
               setJoinedWhitelist(true)
          }catch(err){
            console.error(err)
          }
      }
    
      const checkIfAddressWhitelisted = async ()=>{
         try{
          // We will need the signer later to get the user's address
          // Even though it is a read transaction, since Signers are just special kinds of Providers,
          // We can use it in it's place
            const signer = await getProviderOrSigner(true)
            const whitelistContract = new Contract(
              WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS ,
              abi,
              signer
            )
            const address = await signer.getAddress()
            const _joinedWhitelist = await whitelistContract.whitelistedAddresses(address)
            setJoinedWhitelist(_joinedWhitelist)
            }catch(err){
          console.error(err)
         }
       }
      
      const getNumberofWhitelisted = async ()=>{
        try{
           const provider = await getProviderOrSigner()
           const whitelistContract = new Contract(
            WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS ,
            abi,
            provider
           )
           const _numOfWhitelisted = await whitelistContract.numAddressesWhitelisted()
           setNumberOfWhitelisted(_numOfWhitelisted)
          
        }catch(err){
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
    
    
      const connectWallet = async ()=>{
       try{
         // Get the provider from web3Modal, which in our case is MetaMask
         // When used for the first time, it prompts the user to connect their wallet
         await getProviderOrSigner()
         setWalletConnected(true)
         checkIfAddressWhitelisted()
         getNumberofWhitelisted()
       }catch(err){
        console.error(err)
       }
      }
    
      
      const renderButton = async ()=>{
        // const [renderbutton, setrenderbutton] = useState([])
        if(walletConnected){
    
          if(joinedWhitelist){
            return(
              <div className={styles.description}>
                Thanks for joining Whitelist!
              </div>
            )
          }else if(loading){
            return(
             <button className={styles.button}>
               Loading...
             </button>
            )
            
          }
          else{
            return(
              <button onClick={addAddressToWhitelist} className={styles.button}>
                Join The Whitelist
              </button>
            )
          }
         
        }  else{
          return(
            <button onClick={connectWallet} className={styles.button}>
               Connect Your Wallet
            </button>
          )
        }
      }
    
      const editable = document.getElementById("editable")
      
    
    
      // useEffects are used to react to changes in state of the website
      // The array at the end of function call represents what state changes will trigger this effect
      // In this case, whenever the value of `walletConnected` changes - this effect will be called
      useEffect(()=>{
        // if wallet is not connected, create a new instance of Web3Modal and connect the MetaMask wallet
       if(!walletConnected){
          // Assign the Web3Modal class to the reference object by setting it's `current` value
          // The `current` value is persisted throughout as long as this page is open
         web3Modalref.current = new Web3Modal({
          network: "goerli",
          providerOptions: {},
          disableInjectedProvider: false,
        })
        connectWallet()
       }
    
       
      },[walletConnected])
    
      return (
        
        <div>
          <Head>
           <title>Whitelist dApp</title>
           <meta name="description" content="Whitelist-Dapp" />
          </Head>
          
            <div className={styles.main}>
              <div>
              <h1 className={styles.title}>Welcome to Crypto Devs!</h1>
              <div className={styles.description}>
                Its an NFT collection for developers in Crypto.
              </div>
              <div className={styles.description}>
              {numberOfWhitelisted} have already joined the Whitelist
              </div>
                {renderButton()}
             </div> 
             <div >
               <img  className={styles.image} src="./crypto-devs.svg" />
             </div>
            </div>
    
       
          <footer className={styles.footer}>
          Made with &#10084;  by Arpit Jethava
    
          </footer>
        </div>
        
      )
    }
```

Error:
**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Can anyone help me solving this error?

Comment: For non-Ethereum related issues you will get faster answers at stackoverflow.com